# How to store broadcasting data from RPBroadcastSampleHandler when broadcasting finished in local document directory of iPhone?

Tags: ios, replaykit, rpbroadcastsamplehandler

Can anybody help. I want to store broadcasting data from RPBroadcastSampleHandler in local directory of iPhone storage?

Answer (score 0):

You can store data in AppGroup Space.

but, when user click the red button to stop broadcasting, it always terminate suddenly.

Sometimes I even can not send a CFNotification to my app.

If you try to make process live longer, like use dispatch_semaphore_wait. then you will get a SIGKILL sig